# Most Efficient Way to Fetch Large Amount of Data and Write It to Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I am writing a Python Lambda function in AWS that does the following:

- fetch data from an external API using the requests library
- write the data to a postgresql table

The catch: the returned json has only 2 fields that need to be written to the db, but the data is fairly large, and there are thousands (or hundreds of thousands) of entries. What is the most effective Python tool to do this, and also what should be my approach? For example, set up a while loop and retrieve 100 entries at a time? Any suggestions, resources or pseudo code will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: 1) Not clear to me,  are you fetching only the two fields per row from the API?  2) Can the API return a CSV file? Add the information as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this is a simple API so it just returns an ID and a name as json, and these are the two columns in the table that I want to populate. The only thing is that there are hundreds of thousands of rows. I cannot get a CSV from the API.

Comment: Then you are left to batching it, though I would suggest something larger then batch size of 100. Probably in 1000's to 10,000's. As I see you are using Python I will assume `psycopg2` as the database driver. In that case see [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers).